# How to permit endpoints in spring authorization server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot oauth2 authorization server which will provide and authorize tokens. I also want to provide endpoints for user creation. Can you tell me how to permit these endpoints for non-authenticated users? I tried following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        // TODO persist clients details

        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("browser")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password")
                .scopes("ui");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

and authorization server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
                    authorizeRequests
                            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                });
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

and here is endpoint which I want permit:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public UUID create(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        return userService.create(userDto);
    }
}
```

With these configurations I always got response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-12-28T16:01:09.135+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/user"
}
```

I am using spring boot 2. Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable CSRF in your `AuthorizationConfig` class. Try this configuration :

```
http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
        authorizeRequests
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }).csrf(csrf -> {
        csrf.disable();
    });
```

For more information about CSRF, check this website: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF).
Basically, you don't want to allow anybody to POST information on your website, so you allow to POST only if the user can provide a token indicating that he is using your website to POST (the token is provided by your server). In many web applications now, you can disable it, as you are POSTing from many locations... But don't forget the security of your website.